# Arrays.asList return type mismatch confusion

Tags: java, collections

Why does the following not return a list of integers?

```
int[] ints = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
List<Integer> intsList = Arrays.asList(ints); //compilation error
```

But instead a List of `int[]`

While this

```
String[] strings = new String[] { "Hello", "World" };
List<String> stringsList = Arrays.asList(strings);
```

Returns a list of `String`. I am guessing it fails due to it being an array of primitives but why? And how do I actually return a list of `int`.

Comment: You can only have `Object` in a `List`. This precludes a list of int.

Comment: I was hoping it would get autoboxed.

Comment: But List<Integer> gives him a compilation error.

Comment: Great answer in the other question, this may be closed, didn't know the right terms to search for.

Comment: Java doesn't auto box arrays, it only auto-boxes individual primitives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `T` in `List<T>` must be some subtype of `java.lang.Object`, which `int` is not. THe only other interpretation is, as we are using `...` that you are supplying an array of `int[]`, i.e. an `int[][]`. So you get `List<int[]>`.

`String` is a subtype of `Object`, so this works as expected. Also the only way it can work prior to varargs introduction in J2SE 5.0. Generally the interpretation of existing code should not alter between language versions.

Now, if you wanted a `List<Integer>` you could go through and box each integer. If there a lot of these elements in your program then memory may be an issue. You may want to use a third-party library that compactly backs a `List<Integer>` with an `int[]`, or just stick with arrays for primitives. It's unfortunate that Java does not support value types.

Answer (score 7):

It's because `Arrays.asList(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 })` will create a `List<int[]>` with one item, not a `List<Integer>` with five items.

Note however that this would do what you expected:

```
List<Integer> intsList = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

Your other alternatives are:

- to create an `Integer[]` in the first place, or
- to populate your list in a loop

Comment: Yes that I have tried and it does work but with int[] of size million?

Comment: @arynaq Your two options then are either to create an `Integer[]` instead of an `int[]` or to populate your list in a loop.

Answer (score 3):

The method is defined as:
`public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)`

So in your first case, `T` is `int[]` and you are passing a single object to the method (i.e. the array), therefore it returns a list of `int[]`.

I think you are mistaking with `asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` (i.e. 5 items)

Comment: Exactly right. +1 Remember. In Java, you can call a method with arguments that are a variable number of items of type T with an array of type T if you like. That's why the signature is important.

Comment: There is no such thing a `List` of `int` in Java.